# Как лучше построить фрагмент, который будет незначительно отличаться от готового?

Tags: android, android-fragment, рефакторинг

Имеется готовый фрагмент. Необходимо создать новый фрагмент, который будет отличаться от готового только тем, что в нем не будет editText'а, и кнопка в action bar'е имеет немного другую логику. Как лучше построить программу? Не создавать же новый фрагмент и дублировать код готового фрагмента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это разный экран значит лучше создавать. Сегодня у вас там только editText убирается, а через месяц другие запросы в сеть и другой макет.

Если же это просто другое состояние одного и того же экрана то можно и не создавать новый фрагмент. Тут необходимо смотреть на конкретную задачу.

А избегать дублирования можно разными путями. Можно создавать переиспользуемые View или какие-то другие сущности, которые выполняют определенную логику

Comment: спасибо за ответ